# Documentation for regulator framework with device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-driver

I would like to know if there is any documentation for the linux kernel regulator framework with device tree. I am totally lost with consumer name and lists. I need to add consumers from device tree but I cant see consumer list at all in the device tree files.
I am using AM335x based custom board based on TI sitara.

Answer (score 2):

By reading both documentation ([DeviceTree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/) and [Regulator](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/regulator/)) you should be able to find what you want. But as usual the best documentation is the code itself. The driver [ti-abb-regulator](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/regulator/ti-abb-regulator.c) is using the DeviceTree and the Regulator framework.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, Federico has already said, there are so-called **MFD**(MultiFunction) devices. These are often referred **PMIC**(Power Management IC) that are used in conjunction with a SOC from TI. For AM335x it maybe TPS65217, TPS65910A, TPS65910x, TPS650250, etc. If so, that means some of them you can find follow this link: [MFD](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mfd/).

Comment: That is another issue with the device tree. TI and almost all vendors have written dts files and modified frameworks without any documentation on it. Not to mention, none of them are in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking into this myself, and my conclusion is that the setup in device tree is pretty different from the way it's done in the board file.

What you'll need to do is to add your drivers to the device tree as well, and then use the "[name]-supply" notation, e.g.:

```
cpus {
    cpu0 {
        cpu0-supply = <&omap_tps65912_dcdc1>;
    };
};
```

If you look for this in other board files, you'll see how it works.

Comment: I need to understand how processor/vendor DTS are written. In case of frameworks the devices, nodes and sysfs entries are created based on the dts file which is difficult to make out without any documentation. The consumer names are almost impossible to trace in regulator framework ever since the dts came in.